# Windows sharepoint services (WSS 3.0) stsadm not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, wss, stsadm

I am new to powershell. I am trying to backup a sharepoint site using a stsadm command but for some reason I keeps on giving me some error.

Here is what I am doing: 
 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Stsadm –o **backup** –url >http://server< name:port -**filename** path\filename to be used for the backup file

Here is the error I am getting: 
 
*The term 'stsadm' is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again, 
 
At line:1 char:7 
 
+ stsadm <<<< stsadm –o **backup** –url >http://server< name:port -**filename** path\filename to be used for the backup file 
 
+CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:  [], CommandNotFoundException 
 
      +FullyQualifiedErrorID : CommandNotFoundException*

Comment: Could you please enter a more specific comment? There must be dozens of questions here in which "stsadm  not working".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion John. But I am trying to do a site backup and stsadm is something not working for me. So this probably was the best way to put my comment. Sorry again if this is too confusing.

Comment: How about "stsadm is not recognized", since it probably doesn't matter _which_ command you execute?

Comment: It was a case of user permissions, though the error is misleading us, Launch command prompt with wss sysadmin credentials and run the same command from command prompt, it worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stsadm is not a powershell script, it is an executable located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12 or 14 'hive'.

Normally you would refrain from calling stsadm when running powershell as it is effectively deprecated in SharePoint 2010.

You can however change directory to locate the executable and call it if you wish.

[Here is a list of stsadm equivalents in powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621084.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Nat. So if I have use Powershell to backup a single site (within a SiteCollection) how do I do that. I did some research and found out that Sharepoint Designer can no longer be used for the backup and stsadm command is the only way of doing it. How do I use powershell to do the backup of a single site.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no tool to backup a single site, it is always done at the site collection level. This is because a web site is not really seperable from the site collection. So backup the whole site collection.

Comment: Thanks.I can back up Site collection from Central Admin itself. I think that easier. If I just take save a site template (saving the content) will that act as a backup?
In a different note "Save as Template" in SP designer is not active. How do I activate that? I am trying to save template of a publishing site if that's possible?

Comment: Nope, because as soon as the site gets above a certain size the Save as template will fail. It is a really fragile process that is not guaranteed at all.

Comment: See here for more info on Publishing site and Save as template
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/b14e572a-ea17-47b4-93fe-4694451efe35

Comment: Basically SharePoint does not give you an "easy" option for this sort of thing, you are much better off using PowerShell scripts or a Feature to create the things you need in your template, but this may not be an option due to the time it takes to learn and implement these sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

check this blog post => Backup and Restore SharePoint 2010 Site Collection with PowerShell: http://www.bradleyschacht.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-with-powershell/
Perhaps, it is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. But if I really have to back up site collection. I will do it from Central Admin I think that easier. I was hoping to find a solution to back up only some site with in site collection.